# How to create folders and subfolders with average depth

Tags: java, directory, subdirectory

I have a class that creates a root folder "foo" and subfolders in it:

```
public class FolderCreator {

    public static boolean createDirectoriesWithCommonParent(File parent, String...subs) {

        parent.mkdirs();
        if (!parent.exists() || !parent.isDirectory()) {
            return false;
        }

        for (String sub : subs) {
            File subFile = new File(parent, sub);
            subFile.mkdir();
            if (!subFile.exists() || !subFile.isDirectory()) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        createDirectoriesWithCommonParent(new File("test/foo"), "a", "b", "c");
    }
}
```

I set the number SUBFOLDERS_COUNT and I want the folders and subfolders to be created **with average depth = SUBFOLDERS_COUNT/3**.

How can I create folders and subfolders with a given average depth?

Comment: What does this average count mean for this example? Do you want to create `"test/foo/a/b/c"` instead of all, `a`, `b` and `c`, directly in `test/foo`? What to do with a possible fourth subdirectory? The (`int`) average would still be 1, create that one in the root again?

Comment: The subfolders "a", "b", "c" are just an example.
This is what I need:
- I set SUBFOLDERS_COUNT = 9 (for example)
- Three folders are created in the "foo" directory (depth SUBFOLDERS_COUNT / 3) (for example, "a", "b", "c")
- In each of these three subfolders I need to create another folder with average depth = 3.

that is, for example, in folder “a” there will be one subfolder, in folder “b” there will be three subfolders in folder “c” there will be two subfolders. Their total average depth is three.

Your question about the fourth subdirectory I did not understand :(

Comment: Where do you set this `SUBFOLDERS_COUNT`? I cannot see it in the example code...

Comment: This is not in the code example, because I do not know how to do it. I can set the name and number of folders and pass this as parameters to my method `createDirectoriesWithCommonParent`. But I do not know how to implement so that folders are created with average depth. This is my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem!
To solve this task, the following algorithm is suitable:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class FolderCreator {
    private static final int SUBFOLDERS_COUNT = 9;
    private static final String BASE_PATH = "test/foo";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> subFolders = createSubFolders(SUBFOLDERS_COUNT, SUBFOLDERS_COUNT/3);
        for (String subFolder : subFolders) {
            System.out.println(subFolder);
        }
    }

    private static List<String> createSubFolders(int subFoldersCount, int firstLevelFoldersCount) {
        List<String> paths = new ArrayList<>();
        while (firstLevelFoldersCount != 0) {
            String folderName = BASE_PATH;
            Random random = new Random();
            int max = subFoldersCount - firstLevelFoldersCount + 1;
            int depth = firstLevelFoldersCount == 1 ? subFoldersCount : 1 + random.nextInt(max);
            firstLevelFoldersCount--;
            subFoldersCount -= depth;
            for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++) {
                int layerNumber = i + 1;
                int sequenceNumber = 0;
                folderName = folderName + "\\" + layerNumber + "st" + "LayerSubFolder" + sequenceNumber;
                while (paths.contains(folderName)) {
                    sequenceNumber++;
                    folderName = folderName.substring(0, folderName.length() - 1) + sequenceNumber;
                }
                paths.add(folderName);
                File file = new File(folderName);
                file.mkdirs();
            }
        }
        return paths;
    }
}
```

The folder structure will as shown in the picture for example:

[image: The folder structure will as shown in the picture for example]